# Add text to input field via jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, click, this

I need to add a text to input text field after clicking on a button. The button class is always the same (".button") so I think that I need to use "$(this)" but I don't know how to do it.

My code is:

HTML:

```
<div class="add">
    <input type="text" name="input[1]" value="" class="input[1]">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="add">
</div>
<div class="add">
    <input type="text" name="input[2]" value="" class="input[2]">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="add" value="add">
</div>
<div class="add">
    <input type="text" name="input[3]" value="" class="input[3]">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="add">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent('input[type=text]').val('hhh');
});
```

Regards :)

Comment: `$(this).prev().val('hhh');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev) for `.parent()` ; `input type="text"` appear to be `.previousElementSibling` of `.button` element

```
  $(this).prev("input[type=text]").val("hhh");
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use closest

```
$(this).closest('input[type="text"]').val('hhh')
```